WebSocket connection to ‘'wss://myserver.site.com/api/graphql’ failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
The below setup seems to work fine on Safari, Mozilla.
At times it works fine on some Google Chrome profiles as well. For example if I open multiple profiles of chrome then it works on one and doesn’t in another. I have checked that none oof my extensions block it and no firewall has been imposed.
Further the prolem happens not only for my client but also for GraphQL IDE hence I believe that the client setup may not matter.
Tools and Infra
Client: React 
Server: FastApi, StrawberryApi 
Wildcard SSL for our site using AWS Certificate Manager 
Nginx as reverse proxy from EC2 to myserver.site.com/api/graphql
Client Setup:
REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_URL being myserver.site.com or it’s IP
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink, split } from '@apollo/client'
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities'
import { GraphQLWsLink } from "@apollo/client/link/subscriptions";
import { createClient } from "graphql-ws";




const protocol = process.env.REACT_APP_SSL === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http'
const wsProtocol = process.env.REACT_APP_SSL === 'true' ? 'wss' : 'ws'


const httpLink = new HttpLink({
   uri: `${protocol}://${process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_URL}/api/graphql`,
})




const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
   createClient({
       url: `${wsProtocol}://${process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_URL}/api/graphql`,
       options: {
           reconnect: true,
           lazy: true,
           minTimeout: 10000,
       },
   }),
);


const splitLink = split(
   ({ query }) => {
       const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
       return (
           definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
           definition.operation === 'subscription'
       )
   },
   wsLink,
   httpLink
)


const client = new ApolloClient({
   link: splitLink,
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})


export default client

Server Setup:
import strawberry
from fastapi import FastAPI
from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQLRouter
from typing import AsyncGenerator


@strawberry.type
class Query:
   hello: str = "Hello world"


@strawberry.type
class Subscription:
   @strawberry.subscription
   async def count(self) -> AsyncGenerator[int, None]:
       for i in range(1, 11):
           yield i


schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)
graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema)


app = FastAPI()


app.add_middleware(
   CORSMiddleware,
   allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
   allow_credentials=True,
   allow_methods=["*"],  # Allows all methods
   allow_headers=["*"],  # Allows all headers
)




app.include_router(graphql_app, prefix="/api/graphql")

Nginx Configuration
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name myserver.site.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}

Error received on browser console:
WebSocket connection to 'wss:///myserver.site.com/api/graphql' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

Subscription error: Error: Socket closed
at Object.error (index.ts:69:17)
at client.mjs:424:18

In Network Tab: 
Message: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled 
No Request Headers as it shows Provisional headers are shown
Additional Context
I tried the nginx config below as well, but no luck
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
default upgrade;
   ''      close;
}
upstream websockets {
   server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443;
   server_name myserver.site.com;
   location /api/graphql {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

       # Additional headers for WebSocket
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

       # Timeouts for long-lived WebSocket connections
       proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
       proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
       proxy_connect_timeout 86400s;
      
   }
}

I tried to make listen 443; -> listen 443 ssl; But I don't have certificate configurations to add here. And the wildcard SSL is already applied through AWS.
